# Is "persönlichen" in "alle persönlichen Sachen" Schwache Flexion or Gemischte Flexion?

Tags: declension

I'm having trouble understanding which flexion is used in this phrase starting with "alle". Should I consider "alle" to be the same as "the" or "ein"?

Answer (score 1):

Here are sentences that are morphologically well-formed.

> Die persönlichen Sachen sind im Beutel zu verstauen.
>
> Alle persönlichen Sachen gehören in den Beutel.
>
> Eine persönliche Sache sollte nicht öffentlich diskutiert werden.
>
> Fünf persönliche Gegenstände können mitgenommen werden.
>
> Der persönliche Gegenstand ist am Leibe zu tragen.
>
> Den persönlichen Gegenstand bitte nicht verschlucken!
>
> Meine persönlichen Sachen habe ich zuhause gelassen.
>
> Persönliche Sachen sind zuhause zu lassen.
>
> Persönlichen Sachen ist ein Zettel anzuheften.
>
> Allen persönlichen Sachen ist ein Begleitschreiben beizulegen.
>
> Meine persönlichen Angelegenheiten **[Nominativ]** sind über seine persönlichen Angelegenheiten **[Akkusativ]** mit deinen persönlichen Angelegenheiten **[Dativ]** verbunden und bilden damit praktisch so etwas wie eine Untergruppe unserer persönlichen Angelegenheiten **[Genitiv]**.

Does this help?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but are you answering the question whether it's weak or mixed inflection and maybe with a hint how to figure this out by yourselves.

Comment: I am not knowledgable enough in the theoretical side of German grammar (i.e. putting things into categories) so I cannot tell what is weak and what is mixed inflexion. But I am professional in the practical side of it (i.e. using things correctly) so I can give well-formed examples. I suppose a person asking for weak and mixed inflexion will be able to draw the right conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

Alle is equal to all. (All Personal Things)
It seems to be a schwache Flexion. 
Thing = die Sache which has a feminin Artikel 
Based on the Information provided here http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/gruwi.ansicht?v_id=4067 - especially the Tables it should be a weak flexion.

Comment: Could you decide on whether you want to reply in English or in German? That mixing makes it hard to read.